# cdf plot r for data different row number

Tags: r, cdf

I am trying to make a cdf plot for data with a lot of rows, I made a function:

```
Cdf3<-function(a,b,c){
df <- data.frame(x = c(a$Speed,b$Speed,c$Speed),ggg = factor(rep(1:3, c(nrow(a),nrow(b),nrow(c)))))
df <- df[order(df$x), ]
df$ecdf <- ave(df$x, df$ggg, FUN=function(x) seq_along(x)/length(x))
ggplot(df, aes(x, ecdf, colour = ggg)) + geom_line() + scale_colour_hue(name="my legend", labels=c('2011','2012','2013'))
}
```

The message I am getting is:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 32.0 Mb
>       In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
>       Error during wrapup: cannot allocate vector of size 32.0 Mb

I tried also to do row by row without the function and when I run row ggplot it shows the same massage, am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to make cdf? 
Finally I would like to run it on 5 data sets (not just 3) and each one of them has at least 5M rows.

Comment: Why not use the `ecdf()` function?

Comment: can you explain yourself more please?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `ecdf` using `?ecdf`. It plots the empirical cumulative distribution function, which I gather is what you're after.